# Is there an invalid PKCS#12 password when generating with Ansible openssl_pkcs12 module?

Tags: java, ansible, openssl

I am trying to generate a PKCS12 file using Ansible [`openssl_pkcs12`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/openssl_pkcs12_module.html) module. I am successfully able to generate the certificate but when I am trying to import it to `tlsKeyStore` in my CentOS VM or open manually it always says invalid password. But the password is correct.

But if I generate the same PKCS12 certificate manually using `openssl` command from the same CentOS VM, I am able to import it to the `tlsKeyStore` and can open as well with the same password.

Below is the snippet of code:

```yaml
- name: Generate PKCS#12 file
  openssl_pkcs12:
    action: export
    path: server_cert-ca.p12
    friendly_name: Test
    passphrase: xxxx
    privatekey_path: server-privatekey.pem
    certificate_path: server_cert.pem
    state: present
  loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Below is the Error while importing:

```sh
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server_cert-ca.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore tlsKeyStore -deststoretype jks
Importing keystore server_cert-ca.p12 to tlsKeyStore...
Enter destination keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
Enter source keystore password:  
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
```

Could someone comment whether there is something wrong with this Ansible module?

Comment: Making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using a disposable password (aka `p@ssw0rd`) would help us (and you) know what _problem_ you're actually experiencing. For example, if your `passphrase:` is a jinja2 expression, it can be inadvertently coerced by ansible. Or newlines or whitespaces ... the details matter

Comment: Thanks for the comment...now I tried changing the password (p@ssw0rd) with your suggestion as temp and ending up again in same error.

Even the password I was using was very simple cisco123

Comment: "_Could someone comment whether there is something wrong with this Ansible module?_", sure. I haven't found an issue. The module seems to be OK. It is just working as designed and expected. So I wasn't able to produce an error, unless I am using an incorrect password or not the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
~/test$ pwd
/home/user/test
```

A minimal example playbook `pkcs12.yaml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Generate PKCS#12 file
    openssl_pkcs12:
      action: export
      path: "{{ ansible_nodename }}.p12"
      friendly_name: Test # alias
      passphrase: "P4ssw0rd" # of the P12 file
      privatekey_path: "/etc/pki/tls/private/{{ ansible_nodename }}.key"
      certificate_path: "/etc/pki/tls/certs/{{ ansible_nodename }}.pem"
      state: present
```

will result into a [P12 file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) generated and further results

```sh
# Create JKS file
~/test$ sudo keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore $(hostname).p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore tlsKeyStore -deststoretype jks
Importing keystore test.example.com.p12 to tlsKeyStore...
Enter destination keystore password: # of the JKS file
Re-enter new password: # of the JKS file
Enter source keystore password: # of the P12 file
Entry for alias test successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled

# Check JKS file
~/test$ keytool -list -keystore tlsKeyStore
Enter keystore password: # of the JKS file
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

test, Apr 27, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 00:00:00 ...
```

To summarize, I am not able to reproduce an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for testing...Eventually I fixed the issue by reinstalling my ansible in a Virtual env and also I set the keytool env variable as below:

```
- name: Generate PKCS#12 file
  openssl_pkcs12:
    action: export
    path: server_cert-ca.p12
    friendly_name: Test
    passphrase: xxxx
    privatekey_path: server-privatekey.pem
    certificate_path: server_cert.pem
    state: present
  loop: "{{ my_list }}"
  args:
     executable: "/bin/keytool"
```